# How to get count of related tasks and display in case object using process builder/flows, we should not use customization for this

Tags: process-builder, flow, visual-flows

I have a requirement where we need to get the related task count for a case and show on case record. We dont want to use customization(trigger logic).
I have tried with flows but not able to achieve this. Could anyone please help me in this. Can we achieve this with flows/process builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from below post :

https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/create-roll-up-summary-field-to-count-contacts-on-account-with-process-builder-and-flows/

Comment: Please can you post more information that just a link in the answer.  Even if the linked content will fully answer the question.